# Keycloak stuck in "Loading the admin console"

Tags: docker, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak 20.0.5, and when I go to the Administration Console, Keycloak stays stuck on the "Loading the admin console" page. How can I solve this?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest as builder

# Enable health and metrics support
ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true

# Configure a database vendor
ENV KC_DB=mysql

ENV KC_TRANSACTION_XA_ENABLED=false

ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false
ENV KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true

WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
# for demonstration purposes only, please make sure to use proper certificates in production instead
RUN keytool -genkeypair -alias localhost -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 365 -keystore server.keystore -dname "cn=Server Administrator,o=Acme,c=GB" -keypass secret -storepass secret
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

# change these values to point to a running postgres instance
ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:mysql:ip
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=secret
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=localhost

ENV KC_PROXY=edge
ENV PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start", "--optimized"]
```

I have already done extensive research on the topic, but none of the solutions found have resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

- [This workaround](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/14586#issuecomment-1263510455) is still needed on the entrypoint:

```
entrypoint: "/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start --optimized --proxy=edge --hostname-strict=false"
```